# Grunt Build Stuck at 99% | svgmin:dist

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I have my website on AngularJs, I recently performed **clean up** using TortoiseGit but after that grunt build is not working.

I tried to clone the same project to another machine but same issue grunt build is unable to complete the process

```
$ grunt build
```

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

> > 46 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

```
Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 3 files

Done.


Execution Time (2019-03-20 13:18:51 UTC+5:30)
loading tasks  15ms  ██████████████████ 38%
copy:styles    25ms  ██████████████████████████████ 63%
Total 40ms

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Total saved: 202.19 kB

Done.


Execution Time (2019-03-20 13:18:51 UTC+5:30)
svgmin:dist  2.5s  █████████████████████████████████████████████████ 99%
Total 2.5s
```

**Update**
After grunt build -v stuck here

> ```
> Total saved: 202.19 kB
> ```

```
Done.


Execution Time (2019-03-20 14:52:16 UTC+5:30)
loading tasks  20ms  █ 1%
svgmin:dist    2.7s  ███████████████████████████████████████████████ 99%
Total 2.7s
```

Comment: you should use `grunt build -v` to run Grunt in verbose mode and it will give you more information in the build process.

Comment: I used this command it stuck here     Total saved: 202.19 kB

    Done.


    Execution Time (2019-03-20 14:52:16 UTC+5:30)
    loading tasks  20ms  █ 1%
    svgmin:dist    2.7s  ███████████████████████████████████████████████ 99%
    Total 2.7s

Comment: i suggest you post the full log here, or it's hard to tell why it stuck at 99%

Comment: @iKoala Here it is: https://codeshare.io/aV0ZJ8

Comment: No Reply from anyone am still stuck with this issue